# Accessing Object within Array

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have the following output:

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 20
        [news_title] => Startup finance docs in GitHub
        [news_url] => http://venturebeat.com/2013/03/06/fenwick-west-github/
        [news_root_domain] => venturebeat.com
        [news_category] =>
        [news_submitter] => 4
        [news_time] => 2013-03-06 11:20:03
        [news_points] => 0
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 21
        [news_title] => The problems with righteous investing
        [news_url] => http://gigaom.com/2013/03/07/the-problems-with-righteous-investing/
        [news_root_domain] => gigaom.com
        [news_category] =>
        [news_submitter] => 4
        [news_time] => 2013-03-08 09:14:17
        [news_points] => 0
    )
)
```

How would I access something like news_url in these? I've tried this, but to no avail:

```
print_r $this->$record[0]->news_title;
```

Comment: You probably want: `print_r $this->record[0]->news_title;`, note I removed the `$` in `$record[0]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this:

```
 $arr =    Array();

    $obj0 = new stdClass;
    $obj0->id = 123;
    $obj0->news_title = "some title 0";
    //etc...
    $obj1 = new stdClass;
    $obj1->id = 124;
    $obj1->news_title = "some title 1";
    //etc...

   $arr[0] = $obj0;
   $arr[1] = $obj1;

    print_r($arr);
```

or something like

```
print_r($arr[0]);
```

or even

```
 echo $arr[0]->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using class property, you might want to check if it is accessible first. While accessing the class property after using `$this` you dont need the additional `$`, just use `$this - record`. Like

```
echo $this -> record[0] -> title;
```

If `record` is a valid class property which is an array and it still does not work. Give this a try too:

```
echo {$this -> record[0]} -> title;
```