# PHP For Each Class and Array

Tags: php, for-loop, each

My Array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [name] => name
        [title] => -- 
        [description] => No
        [url] => http://google.com
        [updated] => 1553419890 ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [name] => Hey
        [title] => Title
        [description] => Yes
        [url] =>  http://twitter.com
        [updated] => 1553321131 ) 
)
```

How do I loop the above array with for each?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

//for an array in array

`foreach(name_of_your_array as array) {
        data = array["name"];
    }`

//for an object in your array

`foreach(name_of_your_array as array) {
        data = array->name;
    }`

an example of how you can do

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for how to loop through the array using key-value pair format

```
foreach($name_of_your_records_array As $key => $ object)
{
    $count_of_record = $key;
    $name = $object->name;
    $title = $object->title;
    //...
}
```

Reference link :

[PHP manual foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

[Accessing object inside an array PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409190/accessing-object-within-array)